# Magnolia Cms Oracle Persistence

Tags: oracle, persistence, magnolia

I installed magnolia cms version 5.7 and wanted persistence to be made to an oracle database. Before starting the magnolia instance i updated the relevant configuration files and included the oracle db drivers. When started the instance with "mgnl start" command the tables were created in the database.

But when i am creating new content within the cms (eg users, contacts) data is not stored to the database but somehow it continues persisting via derby.jar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

below you will find the oracle xml bundle which is also set at the magnolia.properties file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Repository PUBLIC "-//The Apache Software Foundation//DTD Jackrabbit 2.0//EN" "http://jackrabbit.apache.org/dtd/repository-2.0.dtd">
<Repository>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource name="magnolia">
      <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe" /><!-- jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe -->
      <param name="user" value="magnolia" />
      <param name="password" value="magnolia" />
      <param name="databaseType" value="oracle"/>
      <param name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
     <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository" />
  </FileSystem>
  <Security appName="magnolia">
    <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager"/>
    <AccessManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.DefaultAccessManager">
    </AccessManager>
    <!-- login module defined here is used by the repo to authenticate every request. not by the webapp to authenticate user against the webapp context (this one has to be passed before thing here gets invoked -->
    <LoginModule class="info.magnolia.jaas.sp.jcr.JackrabbitAuthenticationModule">
    </LoginModule>
  </Security>
  <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="32000"/>
  </DataStore>
  <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default" />
  <Workspace name="default">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/default" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
      <param name="schema" value="oracle" /> 
      <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
      <param name="user" value="magnolia"/>
      <param name="password" value="magnolia"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/><!-- read notes below to set this value properly -->
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
    <SearchIndex class="info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchIndex">
      <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index" />
      <!-- SearchIndex will get the indexing configuration from the classpath, if not found in the workspace home -->
      <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="/info/magnolia/jackrabbit/indexing_configuration_${wsp.name}.xml"/>
      <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true" />
      <param name="minMergeDocs" value="100" />
      <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="3" />
      <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="100000" />
      <param name="mergeFactor" value="10" />
      <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000" />
      <param name="bufferSize" value="10" />
      <param name="cacheSize" value="1000" />
      <param name="forceConsistencyCheck" value="false" />
      <param name="autoRepair" value="true" />
      <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl" />
      <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="true" />
      <param name="resultFetchSize" value="100" />
      <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="3" />
      <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100" />
      <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100" />
      <!-- needed to highlight the searched term -->
      <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
      <!-- custom provider for getting an HTML excerpt in a query result with rep:excerpt() -->
      <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchHTMLExcerpt"/>
    </SearchIndex>
    <WorkspaceSecurity>
      <AccessControlProvider class="info.magnolia.cms.core.MagnoliaAccessProvider" />
    </WorkspaceSecurity>
  </Workspace>
  <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
      <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/workspaces/version" />
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
      <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
      <param name="schema" value="oracle" /> 
      <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
      <param name="user" value="magnolia"/>
      <param name="password" value="magnolia"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/><!-- read notes below to set this value properly -->
      <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
  </Versioning>
</Repository>
```

Comment: The same thing, happens to me on oracle an mysql. Did you ever manage to know why it only creates tables but does not store data?

Comment: Hi @Patriot yes i had figured it out please check the comments on the first answer i also have a link there after Ducaz035 help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the jackrabbit configuration. I assume you have already changed magnolia.properties file in order to use the jackrabbit-bundle-oracle-search.xml. If that's not the case please change that one. Something else to keep in mind is to check the threshold for DataStore (typically binary files are stored elsewhere if they are above a certain threshold) maybe that is the case for you. However, if both are not the case, the best is to copy here the configuration that you have problems with.

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: thanks Ducaz035 for your answer.yes I changed the filesize threshold that goes to datastore but nothing.i included the xml file in the question above so as for you to see. Maybe this should be done on a fresh instance?thanks again

Comment: Can you change LocalFileSystem to OracleFileSystem and FileDataStore to DbDataStore?

Comment: Also apparently there are two different versions of OraclePersistenceManager. Should you use a version prior to 10 we should be using Oracle9PersistenceManager

Comment: hey after your hint i checked the packages that had to do with OracleFileSystem and FileDataStore and seems to have some persistence in some tables :) some others not but i have to check the cms generally now. thanks a lot Ducaz035

here is the link if someone is interested

http://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.12/index.html?org/apache/jackrabbit/core/fs/local/package-summary.html